# Move users and passwords from one wordpress site to another

Tags: users, migration, import

I need to copy over Wordpress users with roles/passwords intact to a new install. I'd prefer not to copy the entire site (though if I have to I will.)

Currently I only have the one main admin account on the new install. Some people have mentioned importing the old user and user-meta tables from the original database, but others have said this could cause problems.

Comment: Since it's a new install there shouldn't be problems copying the user and user-meta tables. The point where you'd run into issues is if you had already created content in the new site and the author IDs didn't match up to anything in the copied user/user-meta tables.

Answer (score 0):

I use the WP Clone plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/#reviews  to 'clone' an existing site to a new site. Quite easy to use: install on 'old'' site then backup; install on new site, restore from the backup url you get  during the backup.

Quite easy to use, and usually reliable. I've sometimes had to backup/restore a second time to get it to work, but not a big effort. You'll need to log into the new site using an admin user from the old site after the restore.

Easy enough to clear out content, etc. Have used it many times; good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to copy the entire site just export the tables `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` from your old site's database and copy them into your new site's database.

Comment: did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily migrate your WordPress users including their password using this free [WordPress user import plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/)